# Why does cellpadding="0" not remove vertical padding around small images?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I put two tiny images (8px) in a table with no cell padding, but there still is padding above and below the pictures. This only happens with images below a certain size. Why?

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><IMG SRC="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/ba/Star.svg/8px-Star.svg.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><IMG SRC="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/ba/Star.svg/8px-Star.svg.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use `cellpadding`. Use CSS.

Comment: Your `<img>` tags don't have a `>` at the end.

Comment: @AtesGoral Update: the problem still persists.

Comment: have you used the element inspector in your browser to see what styles are being added to the elements?

Comment: Is there some CSS tied to the `<img>` element?

Comment: My answer below explains this issue more precisely than the accepted answer referenced in the _marked as duplicate_ message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the image is `inline` and thus renders at the current `line-height`.

Set `line-height` to `8px` or set the image to `block`:

```
td {
    line-height: 8px;
}
```

or ..

```
td img {
    display: block;
}
```